# Write Function to Calculate Percentage and Place it in a New Column of the Data Frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe, percentage, summary

I have a data frame where an athlete receives a performance rating of "Good", "Fair" and "Poor".

I would like to write a function that does the following:

Produces a new data frame that contains
The name of the athlete
The percentage of times the athlete received a "Good" rating

```
Player <- c("Jordan", "Jordan", "Jordan", "Jordan", "Jordan", "Jordan", 
"Jordan","Jordan","Jordan", "Barkley", "Barkley", "Barkley", "Barkley", 
"Barkley", "Olajuwon", "Olajuwon", "Olajuwon", "Olajuwon", "Olajuwon", 
"Kemp", "Kemp", "Kemp", "Kemp", "Kemp", "Kemp")

Rating <- c("Good", "Fair", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Poor", "Good", "Good",  
"Good", "Fair", "Fair", "Poor", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Fair", "Good", 
"Fair", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Good", "Poor")

df <- data.frame(Player, Rating)
```

I would want output that is:

```
Player    PercentGood
Jordan    77.8%
Barkley   40.0%
Olajuwon  60.0%
Kemp      83.3%
```

When I receive the file the percent is not included so I want to run this each time an updated file is sent to me.

So the file is sent, I apply code and a new data frame is produced that gives me a summary of the percentage that an athlete received a rating of "Good"

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution using `scales::percent` to format for percentage.

It first makes a new variable `good` or not encoded as 1 or 0. Then the percentage of 1s is calculated for each player.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
df %>% mutate(good = ifelse(Rating == "Good", 1, 0)) %>% 
  group_by(Player = fct_inorder(Player)) %>% 
  summarise(PercentGood = percent(mean(good)))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Player   PercentGood
#  <fct>    <chr>  
#1 Jordan   77.8%  
#2 Barkley  40.0%  
#3 Olajuwon 60.0%  
#4 Kemp     83.3%
```

Comment: Thank you very much. May you please confirm or correct my understanding:
You call mutate on the df because we are adding a column to the data frame. The new column will contain 1s and 0s based on the Rating being equal to "Good". In this case, "Good" is 1 and all others are 0.
You then group by Player and order it on when the name appeared and then the summarise formats, as you stated above. Sorry for the extra writing, just want to make sure I truly understand it and I'm not just copying stuff for the sake of it. Thank you again.

Comment: Exactly right. `fct_inorder()` is a little trick from the `forcats` package to keep it in the same order as the original data frame, because otherwise `group_by()` puts the players into alphabetical order.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and additional info. Not sure how valuable the rating system is, but as an FYI I can't up-vote because my reputation is too low. Really appreciate your help.